# Incorrect reputation change reported in the achievements menu

Tags: bug

I [answered a question a while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073699/pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript/10073761#10073761) that regularly gets an upvote every week or so. The achievements menu though is currently reporting that it’s earned me +956 rep recently, which would be nice if it was true but definitely isn’t. Has the calculation code around this changed recently?

[image: +956 rep has been added to the ‘Older’ section]

Comment: *"Older"* != "*recently"*, surely?

Comment: It might have done, considering it's in Older which is all time before 30 days ago. There are a log of upvotes for that answer, so it looks feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your screenshot, there is a total of 966 reputation for that question. I noticed it had 2 downvotes, without those it would have been 970, which means 97 upvotes.

But actually your answer has 111 upvotes, so maybe there are more recent rep changes not included in your screenshot. But anyway, you HAVE earned a lot if your rep from that answer,

Comment: Huh, I should have done the maths but yes, you’re right.